# Using an Array of pointers to copy a PPM Image

Tags: c++

So, I tried to write a program that would take in a PPM image and make a new copy of it.

I accomplished it using a flat array to hold the raw pixel data and using `fwrite` to write to a new image. However, when tried to use a "2-D" array to achieve the same results but I kept getting a seg. fault and I'm not sure how to fix it.

These are my classes:

ppmWriter.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ppmWriter.h"
int ppmWriter(const char *filename,int **array, int *width, int *height)
{
    const int max = *width**height*3;
    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", *width, *height);
    unsigned char* rgb;
    int *newarray = new int[*width**height*3];
    int* flat = array[0];
    int nelements = *width**height;
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<nelements; ++i) // loop for w*h times and each iteration fills in 3 slots-r,g,b- of the
    {
        rgb = (unsigned char*)(&(flat[i]));
        newarray[index++]=rgb[0];
        newarray[index++]=rgb[1];
        newarray[index++]=rgb[2];
    }
    fwrite( flat, sizeof(char),max,fp);

    fclose(fp);
    printf("OK - file %s saved\n", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Main.cc

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ppmWriter.h"
#include "ppmReader.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int width, height;
    int ** array = ppmReader("test.ppm",&width,&height);
    ppmWriter("test2.ppm", array , &width, &height);
}
```

ppmReader.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ppmReader.h"
int **ppmReader( const char *filename, int *width, int *height)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    unsigned char *buff;
    int s,h,w;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp,"P6\n%d %d\n255\n", &w, &h);
    *width=w ;
    *height=h;
    s= h*w*3;
    buff= new unsigned char[s];
    fread(buff,sizeof(char),s,fp);
    fclose(fp);

// Initiates a Numerical Recepies Trick array ( pointer to a pointer to and int array, aka 2D array)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    unsigned char* rgb;
    int** array = new int*[w];
    *array = new int[w*h];
    for(int j=1; j<h; ++j)
    {
        array[ j ] = array[ j-1] + w;

    }
//1-loop traversing through array
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    int* flat = array[0];
    int nelements = w*h;
    for(int i=0; i<nelements; ++i)
    {
        rgb = (unsigned char*)(&(flat[i]));
        rgb[i] = *(buff++);
        rgb[i+1] = *(buff++);
        rgb[i+2] = *(buff++);
        rgb[i+3] = 0;
    }

    return array;
}
```

And header files:

```
#ifndef ppmReader_h
#define ppmReader_h

#include <stdio.h>

int **ppmReader( const char *filename, int *width, int *height);

#endif /* ppmReader_h */
```

and

```
#ifndef ppmWriter_h
#define ppmWriter_h

#include <stdio.h>

int ppmWriter(const char *filename, int** array, int *width, int *height);

#endif /* ppmWriter_h */
```

I'm essentially allocating the data into a 2-D array and then 'trying' to revert this process and write it out to a flat array and write it to the image.

Comment: Use the correct language tags. This is not C!. And there is no multidimensional array on your code either. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: I already tagged the correct language. If your prof holds that as a C course he really should learn the language. `buff= new unsigned char[s]` is not valid C, but C++. The same if this code is symptomatic what he teaches, C++ provides other constructs. And if he told something like `char **` is a 2D array (or a pointer to one) he also needs to do some research. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: I believe the term he used was a pointer to a pointer but it made more sense to call it a 2-D array I'm guessing. But you are right nonetheless.

Comment: Well, if he called it pointer to pointer, he is correct and you should follow his advice. It cannot represent a 2D array. But you are not the first (nor the last) to confuse multidimensional arrays and jagged arrays. It would not even have been the first teacher to spread this wrong information.

Comment: @olaf We were never introduced to the term 'ragged' array so I was not aware. So, in my case I have a multidimensional array but I don't ?

Comment: What is a "ragged" array? And I did not say you should use the term, p-t-p is fine. Just not 2D array. A 2D array **is** a multidimensional array. I think I was clear with my first comment you don't have one..